# ImageButton displays odd behaviour on background color overwrite

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

While setting up an ImageButton, I noticed that it had some gray background color that didn't go with the rest of the UI.

[image]

This was the code for the ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_material"/>
```

But when I tried to overwrite the background to transparent like so:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_material"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

The button completely lost its shape and padding

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: It's the normal behavior of image button on infact any button. if don't want to do that use imageView instead it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Umair. Would you be able to point me to any literature on why this happens? I want to be able to overwrite the background color and have it retain its default shape.

Comment: check my answer. It will help you understand the working of imageButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason imageButton have a background is because it's a button basically with an image instead of text. So according to android documentation:

> **ImageButton** public class **ImageButton  extends ImageView**
>
> Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed
>   or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a
>   regular Button, with the standard button background that changes color
>   during different button states. The image on the surface of the button
>   is defined either by the android:src attribute in the 
>   XML element or by the setImageResource(int) method. To remove the
>   standard button background image, define your own background image or
>   set the background color to be transparent. To indicate the different
>   button states (focused, selected, etc.), you can define a different
>   image for each state. E.g., a blue image by default, an orange one for
>   when focused, and a yellow one for when pressed. An easy way to do
>   this is with an XML drawable "selector." For example:

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <selector
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>      <item android:state_pressed="true"
>            android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
>      <item android:state_focused="true"
>            android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
>      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->  </selector>
```

Save the XML file in your project res/drawable/ folder and then reference it as a drawable for the source of your

> ImageButton (in the android:src attribute). Android will automatically
>   change the image based on the state of the button and the
>   corresponding images defined in the XML. The order of the 
>   elements is important because they are evaluated in order. This is why
>   the "normal" button image comes last, because it will only be applied
>   after android:state_pressed and android:state_focused have both
>   evaluated false. See the Buttons guide.

for more info take a look at the documentation: [Image Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you set the color as a background, and color doesn't have size/dimension.

You can check it with any of image as background and the view will adopt the size of that image.
We can say that background image doesn't support scale type.

Only src support scale type in ImageView or other class that extends ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:background="#000000"`  or

```
imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. Op asked about the reason why this happens not the background.